# Listings: spacing after dots

Tags: listings

[image]

Tex code

```
\lstset
{
    basicstyle          =\footnotesize,
    numbers             =left,
    language            =Java,
    commentstyle        =\textit{ \color{gray}},
    keywordstyle        =\color{blue},
    identifierstyle     =\texttt{ \color{black}},
    breaklines          =true,
    frame               =tlrb,
    frameround          =rrrr,
    tabsize             =2%
}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=scala, columns=fullflexible,caption=Source code]  % Start your code-block
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.event.Logging

class Actor extends Actor {
  val log = Logging(context.system, this)

  def receive = {
    case "test" => log.info("received test")
    case _      => log.info("received unknown message")
  }
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

Simple question: How can I remove the spaces between the dots, for example:

```
import akka. actor. Props
```

Should be

```
import akka.actor.Props
```

Comment: The spaces are the result of the spaces that you put into your style declarations. Replacing `\texttt{ \color{black}}` by `\texttt{\color{black}}` (no space before `\color`) will remove the spaces in the output. However, as egreg in his answer points out, you need declarations for the font changes to take effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use declarations, not `\textit` or `\texttt`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

\lstset
{
    basicstyle          =\footnotesize,
    numbers             =left,
    language            =Java,
    commentstyle        =\itshape\color{gray},
    keywordstyle        =\color{blue},
    identifierstyle     =\ttfamily\color{black},
    breaklines          =true,
    frame               =tlrb,
    frameround          =rrrr,
    tabsize             =2
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=scala, columns=fullflexible,caption=Source code]
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.event.Logging // a comment

class Actor extends Actor {
  val log = Logging(context.system, this)

  def receive = {
    case "test" => log.info("received test")
    case _      => log.info("received unknown message")
  }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]